# How to do Bulk Delete in Elasticsearch C# Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

First of all: I am very new to Elasticsearch and the Nest API in specific.

I found that wonderful answer from Russ Cam concerning bulk ***Insert*** of documents:
[NEST ElasticClient C# bulk insert collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66154032/558239)

I have two Questions:

1. How is the bulk ***Delete*** of documents done in such a way.
2. Is it possible to explicitly specify the index name instead of inferring it from the document type?

Answer (score 0):

Try a [Delete by Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475698/deletebyquery-using-nest-and-elasticsearch). This allows you to construct a query and delete all documents that match it. And yes, you can specify the indices used by passing a string, as in this example:

```
var response = _client.DeleteByQuery<MyClass>(q => q
            .Query(q => q
                // your query here
            )
            .Index("Index_Name_Here")
        );
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not allow to delete a list of arbitrary documents.